# Cómo dar tamaño a un fa fa-icons - HTML

Tags: html, font-awesome, icons

Tengo el siguiente icono "fa fa-bars", el cual le incluyo en mi HTML de la siguiente manera:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" style="color:#FFFFFF;"/></i>
```

Si deseo ampliarlo al doble debería añadir:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x fa-lg" style="color:#FFFFFF;"/></i>
```

¿Y si deseo reducir el tamaño de la imagen? ¿Se podría usar width y height? No me funciona esas propiedades.

`<i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" style="color:#FFFFFF;" width="6" height="6"/></i`>

Comment: Entiendo que estás utilizando una fuente de iconos. Lo que deberías hacer es utilizar `font-size` para cambiar el tamaño de la fuente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes la etiqueta `style` cerrada.

```
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" style="color:#FFFFFF; width:6; height:6;"/></i>
```

Por otra parte, creo que los iconos funcionan con la propiedad font-size.

Comment: efectivamente, las clases fa-lg y demás [usan font-size](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/v4.7.0/less/larger.less)

Comment: Lo solucioné poniéndole en la hoja de estilos al <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg desplegable", un estilo llamado: .desplegable{ font-size: 1em; }

Answer (score 15):

La manera de hacer esto según la [documentación](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/) es así:

```css
i{
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<i class="fa fa-bars fa-xs"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-sm"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-4x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-5x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-10x"></i>
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta. Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema, claro lo puedes hacer con fa-xs ,lg, 2x,3x, etc.Pero si quieres cambiar el tamaño de una etiqueta i .

Y si quieres cambiar el tamaño del icono con font-size , tienes que poner la etiqueta i en  un contenedor ...

Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="container">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>


//estilos

.container {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

espero te sirva